# Compare elements of list of list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list and I need to compare the item 0 and item 2 of all elements. If these items are equals I want to sum item 1 and item 3. To be more clear:

```
list1 = [['diez.hn','Arts','Austria','8'], ['diez.hn','Entertainment','Austria','12']]
element 0 of list1: ['diez.hn','Arts','Austria','8']
element 1 of list1: ['diez.hn','Entertainment','Austria','12']
```

what I need:

```
list_ok = [['diez.hn','Arts - Entertainment','Austria','20']]
```

I tried with something like this:

```
reader = [['diez.hn','Arts','Austria','8'], ['diez.hn','Entertainment','Austria','12']]
reader2 = [['diez.hn','Arts','Austria','8'], ['diez.hn','Entertainment','Austria','12']]
    for item in reader:
        for item2 in reader2:
            if item[0] and item[2] == item2[0] and item2[2]:
                item[1] = item[1] + item2[1]
                item[3] = item[3] + item2[3]
```

Comment: Will `list1` always be of length 2?

Comment: Can you post what problem are you facing after you tried your solution? It is always good to do so.

Comment: Maybe `if item[0] == item2[0] and item[2] == item2[2]:` will do?

Comment: According to your current code, you are checking `if item[0]`, which is attempting to evaluate it as a boolean. You need to do `if item[0]==item2[0]`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach sorts the list, then uses `itertools.groupby()` to group the sublists that have the same element in position 0 and 2:

```
import itertools
import operator

list1.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0, 2))

list_ok = []

for k, group in itertools.groupby(list1, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 2)):
    group = list(group)
    list_ok.append([
        k[0], 
        ' - '.join(item[1] for item in group), 
        k[1], 
        str(sum(int(item[3]) for item in group)), 
    ])
```